# Unity 3D - CSG / Geomodding meshes runtime

Tags: unity, mesh

Although I'm not very advanced in Unity, I've been looking into CSG/boolean mesh deformation to see what's possible. I want to break a hole in basic wall meshes at the point the player clicks on, similar to this in Red Faction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loDmdpi0q3g

This article is by the guy who made the geomod feature in Red Faction saying how he did it:
https://web.archive.org/web/20100109011210/http://john.slagel.com/Geomods.html

To my surprise I can't really find anything online for Unity regarding tutorials/vids or anything. So I wondered if its something that's not possible in Unity for some reason?

If it is, I am assuming I would need to use collision contact points followed by meshfilter editing to do it?

Comment: Unity exposes a Mesh class that lets you create and edit mesh data at runtime, in addition to more advanced techniques involving compute shaders and Graphics.DrawProcedural. So yes, this is possible. Can you show us what you've tried so far and where you've run into a step you need help with?

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. All I got to was making a list of collision contact points when my cube explosion hit something it should modify. But for mesh editing I felt I was treading in highly advanced waters so I came on here to ask if it was possible before moving any further. Although I will return to it soon, I attempted a different method after that and tried replacing mesh sections with smaller rigidbodied cubes that splinter on impact. That worked but framerate wasn't great, so I'll try merging remaining meshes etc